# Is there an 'infinite cycling loop' in ORAS, similar to the Lumiose City Tower in XY?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In XY it was really easy to level daycare Pokemon, raise Happiness, hatch eggs, and perform other step-based tasks, due to the infinite riding loop around Lumiose Tower, as seen here:

[image: Lumiose Tower, seen from above]

As you walk/ride in either direction, the camera pans around the tower, and so on until you end up where you started.

Is there a similar place in Pokemon Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes!

At the Battle Resort, the camera pans around as you ride around the island. You can hold 'Up' continuously as the camera swings around.

The perfect line is right up against the daycare kid, but the way to start the loop is to go to this point (just to the left of the Pokemon Center):

[image: Battle Resort, player character against the water.]

This way, you can hold 'up' just as the camera pans around, meaning you continue heading left whilst still holding 'up'.

It's more beneficial than in XY, as you have the daycare and the IV checker close at hand as well.

Here's a video showing the process:

#### Sources

- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/2n4i5l/just_found_a_continous_path_for_breeding_in_oras/)
- Personal Experience

Comment: If you want to continuously use this loop, I suggest you stick either a five cent or a penny to lock the Circle pad in place. Someone did this for 4 hours and their level 40 pokemon (In the daycare) had gone up 30 levels!

Answer (score 3):

There's also one in Mauville City: in the little shops on the walls, if you line up with the top-left corner in one of them and hold down the circle pad at a diagonal down-right angle it infinitely loops.

I don't think anyone else knows about it.

Comment: Cool! Nice find!

Comment: thx the angles not very hard actually

Comment: also with this one you dont have to beat the game first i did it for about 24 hrs and went from level 27 to level 93